# How can I sort by 2 keys from a list of dictionary?

Tags: java, list, sorting, dictionary

list = [{"tools":12,"id":1,"time":"2020-09-28"}, {"tools":11,"id":4,"time":"2021-10-24"}, {"tools":18,"id":3,"time":"2019-09-24"}]

//sort the list by "id" and "time"

Comment: Will there be objects with same ID?

Comment: Is this Java or JavaScript?

Comment: The objects will have different IDs

Comment: It is in Java ..............

Answer (score 1):

you can use Java8 grammar，Stream as follow:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Sorting> list = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Sorting> result = list.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(Sorting::getId).thenComparing(Sorting::getTime)).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
//Demo class
static class Sorting{
    private Integer id;
    private Integer tools;
    private LocalDateTime time;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public Integer getTools() {
        return tools;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getTime() {
        return time;
    }
}
```